# H1N1 question probability

Tags: probability

> A diagnostic test for H1N1 virus infection is 95 percent accurate, in that
>   if a person is infected with the H1N1 virus, the test will detect it with a probability of 0.95, and if a person is not infected with the H1N1 virus, the test will give a negative result with a probability of 0.95. Suppose that only 0.5% of the population is infected
>   with the H1N1 virus. One person is chosen at random from this population. The
>   diagnostic test indicates that this person is infected. What is the probability that this person is actually not infected?

So far, all I have is: 
$$P(\text{positive test} \,|\, \text{truly infected}) = 0.95\\
P(\text{negative test}\, |\, \text{truly infected}) = 0.05\\
P(\text{H1N1 infected}) = 0.005 \implies P(\text{not H1N1 infected}) = 0.995?$$

Do I have it correct so far? 
I get stuck here...
We are supposed to find $P(\text{positive test} \,| \,\text{not infected})$, correct?

Thank you for help in advance guys!

Comment: You're correct so far, except that we're after P(not infected | positive test). Heard of [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)?

Comment: Yes, I understand the Bayes's theorem but I always get confused when it comes to conditional probability. Anyways, from what you hinted me  I let $P(not infected) = P(H1N1 not infected)$ from the question above and $P(truly infected) = P(H1N1 infected)$. So I have: $P( not infected|positive test) = (P(positive test|not infected) P(not infected))/(P(positive test|truly infected) P(truly infected) + P(positive test|not infected) P(not infected))$

Comment: Just a suggestion, you could write $T, \bar{T},I, \bar{I}$ for respectively *positivetest, negativetest, infected, notinfected*. The formulas will be much easier to read, and look more like the Bayes theorem as it is written on wiki or in your reference book - which makes it easier to apply.

Answer (score 1):

The above comments are all correct, the result should be as following:

$$1 - \frac{0.5\% \times 95 \%}{0.5\% \times 95 \% + 99.5\% \times 5\%} = 1-\frac{95}{95+995} = 0.9128
$$